# Enable automatic plugin update for certain plugins

Tags: automatic-updates

It seems there's only [a global option](http://codex.wordpress.org/Configuring_Automatic_Background_Updates#Plugin_.26_Theme_Updates_via_Filter) where users can enable it. Is there a way to bypass this for only a certain plugin?

So I can move this to either to my plugin options or enable it by default (only for my plugin of course)

Comment: Thanks, didn't find it in the first place. Please close!

Answer (score -1):

You can do it with this plugin  http://wordpress.org/plugins/automatic-updater/ and this tricks : http://optimwise.com/exclude-plugins-advanced-automatic-updates-wordpress-plugin/

Comment: Please expand your answer, because if these links go down or changes, they become useless for the readers. Thanks.